# App store validation stage bundle identifier error

Tags: ios, validation, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I want to deploy my app to the apple app store.

after archiving, on the validation stage i'm getting the an bundle id error code.(see image)
my bundle identifier is : "ru.maxiforex.mobile", 
defined in xcode: (.plist and general tab),
and ind the appId in the provisioning profile at apple.dev.

Please advise,
Asaf

Edit:
Ok, bug is fixed:
the bundle identifier on the summary page on the itunes connect was: "maximarkets".
changing this to the real name + deleting the derived data page did the trick.
thanks for the help :)

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the error message really is, but generally you should make sure the you have downloaded your signing identities and provisioning profiles into Xcode. Go to Xcode->Preferences->View details and hit refresh in lower left corner and then try again.

Comment: Did you already release previous version of this app? If that's the case you can't change the bundle identifier.

Comment: bundle identifier has to match the one in the distribution certificate being used

Comment: This is the first version. is there a bundle id in itunes? where can this mismatch take place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sending in an update? Then you need to use the previous bundle id, which according to the error is `maximarkets`.

If you are sending in a new app then you will need to create that app first in itunesconnect.

Comment: this is the first version.app is defined on Itunes.where is this "maximarkets" is taken from?

Comment: From the app you select to submit to iTunes.